# Can't get clipboard information on Android 10

Tags: android

Getting clipboard information in the background
Works fine on android 9
But it doesn't work on android 10

Is there a way to get the clipboard information in android 10?

Thank you

```
clipboard = (ClipboardManager)getSystemService(CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);

clipboard.addPrimaryClipChangedListener(new ClipboardManager.OnPrimaryClipChangedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onPrimaryClipChanged() {


    }
});
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As explained in Android 10 changes:

> Limited access to clipboard data: unless your app is the default input
>   method editor (IME) or is the app that currently has focus, your app
>   cannot access clipboard data on Android 10 or higher.

There is no way around it, you can find more info on the [official docs](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/10/privacy/changes)